# ¿Como obtener la pagina de una fila de una tabla, usando paginacion?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web

Supongamos que tengo una tabla que muestro de forma fija 5 filas o registros, con un total fijo de 12 registros, eso hace que tenga tres paginas para que uno pueda paginar. Pero por ejemplo si yo quiero elegir la fila 8, necesito obtener la pagina en la que se encuentra y guardar ese valor, es decir calcular y obtener el valor de la pagina que es igual a "2". Me gustaría saber como podría obtener ese valor 2, el cual es la pagina en donde se encuentra la fila seleccionada.

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?¿tendría que usar alguna división de la fila seleccionada por el numero de filas a mostrar? 
Lo estoy haciendo en C#, pero da lo mismo e lenguaje,ya que importa el algoritmo

Comment: ¿Que has intentado hasta el momento?. Por favor, actualiza tu pregunta.
Mientras tanto, puedes revisar [estos](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/4228/custom-data-paging-in-asp-net) [enlaces](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1078662/How-to-implement-Paging-in-ASP-NET-at-SQL-Query-Le) o busca `codeproject asp.net paging` en Google.

Comment: No se entiende lo que deseo hacer?? es solo obtener el numero de la pagina que se encuentra una fila x, teniendo como dato, el numero de filas por paginas a mostrar y el total de filas o registros. En donde a través de una suma o división pueda obtener tal valor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta con obtener el resto de la división entera del registro que quieres, entre el No. de registros por página, y sumarle uno si quieres que el primer elemento del indice sea el 1, si no lo trata como si el primer elemento del indice sea el 0. (Que es el que usarias en un array)

Por ejemplo el registro No 8:

```
8 / 5 = 1,6  --> El resto de la división entera es 1 + 1 = 2
```

Para el elemento 12:

```
12 / 5 = 2,4 --> El resto de la división entera es 2 + 1 = 3
```